# Getting position based on the letter

Tags: python, variables, position

Hello this is a little complicated question. I hope you can understand what I'm trying to ask.
Let's say I have:

```
newvar = hoavyeph8
```

There is an 'e' in this var. I want to know which letter is present before e and write the 'if' function.
Like:

```
if I is present before e:
  do something
```

Like this. I want to know the letter present behind the another letter. And write the function. How can I?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Is ```hoavyeph8``` supposed to be a variable or a string?

Answer (score 1):

```
newvar = "hoavyeph8"

for index, c in enumerate(newvar):
  if(c=="e"):
    print(f"{newvar[index-1]} is before e")
```

This will tell you what is before e, I'm not sure what you want to do next.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend first reading TheRavenSpectre's answer, as that is perfectly adequate.  If you want to see other ways, continue reading.

What you are asking can be solved two ways: using the `find()` function, or using regex (regular expressions).  Regex will needlessly complicate it, while `find()` is perfectly adequate here.

Using `find()`, you can do it two ways, depending if you are only looking for one type of preceding letter or multiple (only i before e, or also a before e).  To look for multiple letters:

```
newvar = "this is a test string"
# search for where s is preceded by a space
i = newvar.find('s')
while i != -1:
    if i > 0 and newvar[i - 1] == ' ': # first test that the index of s is not zero so it does not look outside the string
        doSomething(newvar, i - 1)
    i = newvar.find('s', i+1)
```

The other case would be to only look for i before e.  That can be solved as such:
string = "I want you to find the i before e, siE vIe"

```
j = string.lower().find('ie')
while j != -1:
    doSomething(string, j)
    j = string.lower().find('ie', j+1)
```

This code would look for all occurrences of 'ie', regardless of case, perform the operation, then continue looking.